# Как в DataGridBundle (Symfony 3) изменить формат даты?

Tags: php, symfony2, symfony, datagridview, symfony3

В контролере:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
$source = ...

$grid = $this->get('grid');
$grid->setSource($source);

return $grid->getGridResponse('index.html.twig');
}
```

В index.html.twig:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block center %}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        {{ grid(grid) }}
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock center %}
```

В Entity:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 * @Map\Field(type="date", api="date_send")
 */
protected $sendAt;
```

Есть колонка sendAt в Entity она DateTime и она выводится в grid в стандартном формате.
Вопрос:
Как изменить формат даты в Grid( колонки sendAt )в контролере не изменявши структуру Entity ?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно использовать:

```
$grid->getColumns()->getColumnById('sendAt')->setFormat('d.m.Y H:i');
```